# Are plotnine Boxplots following standard conventions regarding Whiskers, IQR and Median?

Tags: plotnine

Is there any information available on what the `geom_boxplot` function of [plotnine](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.geoms.geom_boxplot.html) exactly is showing? I checked the source code but couldn't find a clear definition (such as for seaborn catplot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plotnine `stats` do the calculations, so you can find that information in the [stat_boxplot](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.stats.stat_boxplot.html) documentation.

Comment: Thank you, how did you know that?